# OpenRefine - read-only instance

Tags: openrefine

I want to make an OpenRefine instance available for data exploration, to use its filtering, faceting, clustering and other features. But the users (this would be shared on a network) shouldn't be able to edit anything.

Some ideas, inviting more or clues on how to implement one:

- Make the local project folder read-only.
- Make it non-persistent (ie, user makes changes and OpenRefine pretends along, but next time when they load it all the changes are gone). This actually happens natively in docker and after some frustration we learn how to run the docker image with persistent volumes. But that "resetting" of data only kicks in when one shuts down the instance and restarts it. How can we make it non-persistent within, say, a browser session?
- Inside the code, if there is any flag variable based on which editing decisions are taken, then with a little tinkering could we override it? In this route the yellow alert message that usually comes on top saying this many cells edited would probably say something like "Error: edit failed!". We could tinker it into something more apt like "Sorry, editing is disabled in this instance."

Comment: not exactly what you want but Exhibit provides similar facet browsing functionality to Open Refine... I once wrote an extension of OpenRefine to export the view to Exhibit.. Exhibit at https://www.simile-widgets.org/exhibit3/
My extension (not sure if it still works) https://sheeeer.wordpress.com/2017/01/15/exhibit-extension-for-open-refine/

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is anything built in to disable editing. One thing you could do is disable in the backend all the API commands that are used to make changes, but there is no guarantee that the UI would gracefully reject the actions when the user triggers them.

To disable the API commands, open the `./main/webapp/modules/core/MOD-INF/controller.js` file. You will then need to determine which commands to disable. For instance, you don't want users to delete projects, so you should remove

```
RS.registerCommand(module, "delete-project", new Packages.com.google.refine.commands.project.DeleteProjectCommand());
```

That will make it impossible to delete a project from the UI.

You should also disable commands from the extensions (for instance in `extensions/wikidata/module/MOD-INF/controller.js` for the Wikidata extension).

I have created the corresponding enhancement request here:
https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/1910